# How to split table column into 30% of image and 70% of contents

Tags: html, css, html-table

[image]

I have a table in which I need to split into 2 columns which contain 30% of the image and 70% of the contents. In the 30% of image section 
1.I need a big image
2. Below that, I need 4 small images

HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <th style="width:30%">Image</th>-- I want this to be 30% of the table heading
    <th>Data1</th>
    <th>Data1</th>
    <th>Data1</th>
    <th>Data1</th>
    <th>Data1</th>
    <th>Data1</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of dataa>
      <td> </td>-- I want this to cover 30% of the table, it should have one big image which combines 2 rows and below that, I need small 4 images with 2 images in each row
    <!-- This should be 70% of table column -->
      <td>{{data1}}</td>
      <td>{{data2}}</td>
      <td>{{data3}}</td>
      <td>{{data4}}</td>
      <td>{{data5}}</td>
      <td>{{data6}}</td>
      <td><img></td> 
      <td>{{data7}}</td>
      <td>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
      </td>
      <!-- 70% ends here -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you are looking for old browser support as well?? if not, you css tables instead of html tables...its much cleaner!

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this. The below class is to remove the space between the images.

```css
.images {
  text-align:center;
}

th.width{
  width:30%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th class="width">Image</th>
    <th>Data1</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Website</th>
    <th>Phone No</th>
    <th>E-mail</th>
    <th>Images</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x150" width="100%" /></div>
        <div class="images">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" width="45%" />
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" width="45%" />
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" width="45%" />
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" width="45%" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>{{data1}}</td>
      <td>{{data2}}</td>
      <td>{{data3}}</td>
      <td>{{data4}}</td>
      <td>{{data5}}</td>
      <td>{{data6}}</td>
      <td><img></td>
      <td>{{data7}}</td>
      <td>
        <button></button>
        <button></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160287/discussion-between-naren-murali-and-bhrungarajni).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `bootstrap`'s grid system. It should do the trick and give you a nice responsive table aswell. You can get bootstrap from: [here](https://getbootstrap.com/) After including bootstrap try using the classes for tables and the grid system for styling the table.

[Example source](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tables.asp)

Simple example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Bordered Table</h2>
  <p>The .table-bordered class adds borders to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!